# Slick Slider photos disappearing when clicked, but only after clicking next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I've been trying to implement the slick slider carousel onto my website however I'm having an issue with the logos within the carousel.

Below is an image of the slider. I currently have the carousel set up how I would like, but whenever I click on one of the logo images after having used the navigation arrows, that specific logo and all the ones after it disappear. I'm not sure where I need to look to fix this problem I've been searching and testing codes for quite some time, but I'm not quite sure which code is the one the should be looked at, if anyone can let me know I'll gladly upload it for more assistance. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

[Carousel Slider Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ1Va.jpg)

[Carousel Slider After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yvTP.jpg)

Comment: It seems like a client side error in which case opening up the console log and checking for error messages + examining the embedded object will start you down the path to success.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!! I figured it out, I had to change the Accessibility function under JavaScript from True to False.. GAHHH so much time spent feels great to get it!!